# Unix Command to Print the files from particular number

Tags: unix

Suppose there are 700 files in the directory. How can I print only 101 to 200 ?? Please don't say ls -lrt |head-200|tail -100

Comment: "Please don't say ls -lrt |head-200|tail -100" - why not?

Comment: I want to know if there is any other command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pipe the `ls` output to `sed` :

```
ls -rt | sed -n "101,200 p"
```

- option `-n` means don't print everything
- `101,200` is an expression that selects the lines 101 to 200 and
- `p` means print, but only applied to the selected lines

Of course there are other possibilities like `awk` ( `ls -rt | awk "101<=NR && NR <= 200"` ), too.

Comment: @Srinivas: You could tell THANKS to a person by upvote his/her answer and also by selecting the correct answer you could do it for the users which may refer this thread in future too.